Putting a custom table of contents inside CKEditor in JS
I am trying to create a custom table of contents at the top of my ckeditor (inside the text box). I've successfully set up a ckeditor with vite from https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/builder/. I can see a table of contents appear outside my ckeditor when I set up my divs as
 <div class="toc-container js-toc"></div>
  <div class="main-container js-toc-content">
    <div class="editor-container editor-container_classic-editor editor-container_include-style" id="editor-container">
      <div class="editor-container__editor"><div id="editor"></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>


However, when I try to move this table of contents inside of the CKEditor, it disappears (and inspect shows a height of 0px)
<div class="main-container">
        <div class="editor-container">
          <div class="editor-container__editor">
            <div id="editor" class="js-toc-content ck-content">
              <!-- TOC Container inside the editor content -->
              <div class="toc-container js-toc"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      


Here is the full (not-working) index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor 5 Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="editor-container">
          <div class="editor-container__editor">
            <div id="editor" class="js-toc-content ck-content">
              <!-- TOC Container inside the editor content -->
              <div class="toc-container js-toc"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        <!-- Importing the main.js file -->
        <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
      
        <!-- Initialize tocbot -->
<script type="module">
    import tocbot from 'tocbot';
  
    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), editorConfig)
      .then(editor => {
        // Initialize tocbot after CKEditor is ready
        tocbot.init({
          // Where to render the table of contents.
          tocSelector: '.js-toc',
          // Where to grab the headings to build the table of contents.
          contentSelector: '.js-toc-content',
          // Which headings to grab inside of the contentSelector element.
          headingSelector: 'h1, h2, h3',
          // For headings inside relative or absolute positioned containers within content.
          hasInnerContainers: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem initializing the editor:', error);
      });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>

and the full main.js:
import {
    ClassicEditor,
    AccessibilityHelp,
    Alignment,
    Autoformat,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    Autosave,
    BalloonToolbar,
    Base64UploadAdapter,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    Code,
    CodeBlock,
    Essentials,
    FindAndReplace,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    GeneralHtmlSupport,
    Heading,
    Highlight,
    HorizontalLine,
    HtmlComment,
    HtmlEmbed,
    ImageBlock,
    ImageInline,
    ImageInsert,
    ImageInsertViaUrl,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Italic,
    Link,
    LinkImage,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    Markdown,
    MediaEmbed,
    Mention,
    PageBreak,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromMarkdownExperimental,
    PasteFromOffice,
    RemoveFormat,
    SelectAll,
    SpecialCharacters,
    SpecialCharactersArrows,
    SpecialCharactersCurrency,
    SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,
    SpecialCharactersMathematical,
    SpecialCharactersText,
    Strikethrough,
    Style,
    Subscript,
    Superscript,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableColumnResize,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    TextTransformation,
    TodoList,
    Underline,
    Undo
} from 'ckeditor5';



import 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css';

import './style.css';

const editorConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'undo',
            'redo',
            '|',
            'findAndReplace',
            'selectAll',
            '|',
            'heading',
            'style',
            '|',
            'fontSize',
            'fontFamily',
            'fontColor',
            'fontBackgroundColor',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            'subscript',
            'superscript',
            'code',
            'removeFormat',
            '|',
            'specialCharacters',
            'horizontalLine',
            'pageBreak',
            'link',
            'insertImage',
            'insertImageViaUrl',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'insertTable',
            'highlight',
            'blockQuote',
            'codeBlock',
            'htmlEmbed',
            '|',
            'alignment',
            '|',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'todoList',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'accessibilityHelp'
        ],
        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: false
    },
    plugins: [
        AccessibilityHelp,
        Alignment,
        Autoformat,
        AutoImage,
        AutoLink,
        Autosave,
        BalloonToolbar,
        Base64UploadAdapter,
        BlockQuote,
        Bold,
        Code,
        CodeBlock,
        Essentials,
        FindAndReplace,
        FontBackgroundColor,
        FontColor,
        FontFamily,
        FontSize,
        GeneralHtmlSupport,
        Heading,
        Highlight,
        HorizontalLine,
        HtmlComment,
        HtmlEmbed,
        ImageBlock,
        ImageInline,
        ImageInsert,
        ImageInsertViaUrl,
        ImageResize,
        ImageStyle,
        ImageToolbar,
        ImageUpload,
        Indent,
        IndentBlock,
        Italic,
        Link,
        LinkImage,
        List,
        ListProperties,
        Markdown,
        MediaEmbed,
        Mention,
        PageBreak,
        Paragraph,
        PasteFromMarkdownExperimental,
        PasteFromOffice,
        RemoveFormat,
        SelectAll,
        SpecialCharacters,
        SpecialCharactersArrows,
        SpecialCharactersCurrency,
        SpecialCharactersEssentials,
        SpecialCharactersLatin,
        SpecialCharactersMathematical,
        SpecialCharactersText,
        Strikethrough,
        Style,
        Subscript,
        Superscript,
        Table,
        TableCaption,
        TableCellProperties,
        TableColumnResize,
        TableProperties,
        TableToolbar,
        TextTransformation,
        TodoList,
        Underline,
        Undo
    ],
    balloonToolbar: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'link', 'insertImage', '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
    fontFamily: {
        supportAllValues: true
    },
    fontSize: {
        options: [10, 12, 14, 'default', 18, 20, 22],
        supportAllValues: true
    },
    heading: {
        options: [
            {
                model: 'paragraph',
                title: 'Paragraph',
                class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
            },
            {
                model: 'heading1',
                view: 'h1',
                title: 'Heading 1',
                class: 'ck-heading_heading1'
            },
            {
                model: 'heading2',
                view: 'h2',
                title: 'Heading 2',
                class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
            },
            {
                model: 'heading3',
                view: 'h3',
                title: 'Heading 3',
                class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
            },
            {
                model: 'heading4',
                view: 'h4',
                title: 'Heading 4',
                class: 'ck-heading_heading4'
            },
            {
                model: 'heading5',
                view: 'h5',
                title: 'Heading 5',
                class: 'ck-heading_heading5'
            },
            {
                model: 'heading6',
                view: 'h6',
                title: 'Heading 6',
                class: 'ck-heading_heading6'
            }
        ]
    },
    htmlSupport: {
        allow: [
            {
                name: /^.*$/,
                styles: true,
                attributes: true,
                classes: true
            }
        ]
    },
    image: {
        toolbar: ['imageTextAlternative', '|', 'imageStyle:inline', 'imageStyle:wrapText', 'imageStyle:breakText', '|', 'resizeImage']
    },
    initialData:
        '<h2>Congratulations on setting up CKEditor 5! </h2>\n<p>\n    You\'ve successfully created a CKEditor 5 project. This powerful text editor will enhance your application, enabling rich text editing\n    capabilities that are customizable and easy to use.\n</p>\n<h3>What\'s next?</h3>\n<ol>\n    <li>\n        <strong>Integrate into your app</strong>: time to bring the editing into your application. Take the code you created and add to your\n        application.\n    </li>\n    <li>\n        <strong>Explore features:</strong> Experiment with different plugins and toolbar options to discover what works best for your needs.\n    </li>\n    <li>\n        <strong>Customize your editor:</strong> Tailor the editor\'s configuration to match your application\'s style and requirements. Or even\n        write your plugin!\n    </li>\n</ol>\n<p>\n    Keep experimenting, and don\'t hesitate to push the boundaries of what you can achieve with CKEditor 5. Your feedback is invaluable to us\n    as we strive to improve and evolve. Happy editing!\n</p>\n<h3>Helpful resources</h3>\n<ul>\n    <li> <a href="https://orders.ckeditor.com/trial/premium-features">Trial sign up</a>,</li>\n    <li> <a href="https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/index.html">Documentation</a>,</li>\n    <li>⭐️ <a href="https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5">GitHub</a> (star us if you can!),</li>\n    <li> <a href="https://ckeditor.com">CKEditor Homepage</a>,</li>\n    <li>‍ <a href="https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/">CKEditor 5 Demos</a>,</li>\n</ul>\n<h3>Need help?</h3>\n<p>\n    See this text, but the editor is not starting up? Check the browser\'s console for clues and guidance. It may be related to an incorrect\n    license key if you use premium features or another feature-related requirement. If you cannot make it work, file a GitHub issue, and we\n    will help as soon as possible!\n</p>\n',
    link: {
        addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
        defaultProtocol: 'https://',
        decorators: {
            toggleDownloadable: {
                mode: 'manual',
                label: 'Downloadable',
                attributes: {
                    download: 'file'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    list: {
        properties: {
            styles: true,
            startIndex: true,
            reversed: true
        }
    },
    mention: {
        feeds: [
            {
                marker: '@',
                feed: [
                    /* See: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html */
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    menuBar: {
        isVisible: true
    },
    placeholder: 'Type or paste your content here!',
    style: {
        definitions: [
            {
                name: 'Article category',
                element: 'h3',
                classes: ['category']
            },
            {
                name: 'Title',
                element: 'h2',
                classes: ['document-title']
            },
            {
                name: 'Subtitle',
                element: 'h3',
                classes: ['document-subtitle']
            },
            {
                name: 'Info box',
                element: 'p',
                classes: ['info-box']
            },
            {
                name: 'Side quote',
                element: 'blockquote',
                classes: ['side-quote']
            },
            {
                name: 'Marker',
                element: 'span',
                classes: ['marker']
            },
            {
                name: 'Spoiler',
                element: 'span',
                classes: ['spoiler']
            },
            {
                name: 'Code (dark)',
                element: 'pre',
                classes: ['fancy-code', 'fancy-code-dark']
            },
            {
                name: 'Code (bright)',
                element: 'pre',
                classes: ['fancy-code', 'fancy-code-bright']
            }
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties']
    }
};

ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), editorConfig);

I'd appreciate any pointers here to how to get the table of contents to show up inside the CKEditor. I'm also noticing that clicking on the section titles does not scroll to the section in the example I've tried that does show up. Hopefully, the automatic scrolling will work once the table of contents is inside of the editor.
Finally, if anyone has any better strategies for a WYSIWYG editor that has many features including a built in table of contents for free, I'd be happy to hear about that as well.
Thanks in advance!
